# Change the display of Node in Mindmap in Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to change the display of Node in [Mindmap](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/mindmap.jsf), have you an idea how can I begin with this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download *primefaces-3.X-sources.jar* from [PrimeFaces Downloads](http://primefaces.org/downloads.html) and extract it

In *primefaces-3.X-sources\META-INF\resources\primefaces\mindmap*

You will find *mindmap.js* file , inside it you can see there is a `createNode` function , this function draws the node, primefaces is using [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw the mindmap

You can *play* with that function `createNode` and try to draw some other element , than place that modified js file into your *primefaces-3.X.jar* and check it out...